# custom unwind segue behavior

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unwind-segue

I am new to xcode and swift and am making changes to an existing app. Out of my main view controller I am using a custom segue with an unwind to implement a menu page view that slides out from the left and back in from the right. Two of my menu items, on touch, take you back to the main view controller instead of a view in the stack, and either embed a new screen or show new information. When I use the unwind segue it flashes what it's supposed to quickly but then goes to what is the default of my main controller and I'm wondering how I can fix this issue. My code for the custom segue:

```
class MHLeftSlideSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {

        let src = self.sourceViewController
        let dst = self.destinationViewController

        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-src.view.frame.size.width, 0)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
        }, completion: { finished in
            src.presentViewController(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}

class UIStoryboardUnwindLeftSlideSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {

        let src = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController
        let dst = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController

        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, belowSubview: src.view)
        src.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            src.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-src.view.frame.size.width, 0)
        }, completion: { finished in
            src.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

I am using the first part to segue from my Main VC with a mobil menu button to my Menu VC and the unwind is going back to my Main VC with a close button. The issue I'm having involves a "search" and "top searches" link back to the MainVC. The search info is presented with this code in the Main VC:

```
if MHMainVC.fromSearchMenu == true {
    MHMainVC.fromSearchMenu = false
    setSearchState(!isSearching)
}

@IBAction func onSearch(sender: AnyObject!) {
    setSearchState(!isSearching)
}

func setSearchState(search: Bool) -> Void {
    isSearching = search

    if isSearching == false {
        self.txtSearch.text = nil
        self.txtSearch.resignFirstResponder()
        self.txtSearch.hidden = true
        self.btnSearch.setImage(UIImage(named: "btnSearch"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.constraintLeftSpaceOfSearchButton.constant = 56
        self.btnCalendar.hidden = false
        self.tblSearchResult.hidden = true
    } else {
        self.txtSearch.becomeFirstResponder()
        self.txtSearch.hidden = false
        self.btnSearch.setImage(UIImage(named: "btnClose"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.constraintLeftSpaceOfSearchButton.constant = 8
        self.btnCalendar.hidden = true
        self.tblSearchResult.hidden = false
    }

    updateConstraint(true)
}
```

and the "top searches" code is from MHTopSearchesVC going to a Container VC that embeds in the Main VC and the code for that is

```
class MHContainerVC: UIViewController {

    var currentSegueIdentifier  : String?
    var firstViewController     : MHSplashFeaturesVC?
    var secondViewController    : MHTopSearchesVC?
    var thirdViewController     : ViewController?
    var transitionInProgress    : Bool?

    static var SegueNameKey: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let name = MHContainerVC.SegueNameKey {
            self.currentSegueIdentifier = name
            performSegueWithIdentifier(name, sender: nil)

            MHContainerVC.SegueNameKey = "embedSplashFeaturesVC"
        } else {
            self.currentSegueIdentifier = "embedSplashFeaturesVC"
            performSegueWithIdentifier("embedSplashFeaturesVC", sender: nil)
        }

        self.transitionInProgress = false
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "embedSplashFeaturesVC" {
            self.firstViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? MHSplashFeaturesVC
        }

        if segue.identifier == "embedTopSearchesVC" {
            self.secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? MHTopSearchesVC
        }

        if segue.identifier == "embedBecomeAHelper" {
            self.thirdViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController
        }

        if segue.identifier == "embedSplashFeaturesVC" {
            if self.childViewControllers.count > 0 {
                self.swapFromViewController(self.childViewControllers[0], toViewController: self.firstViewController!)
            } else {
                self.addChildViewController(segue.destinationViewController)

                let destView: UIView = (segue.destinationViewController).view
                destView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
                self.view.addSubview(destView)

                segue.destinationViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
            }
        } else if segue.identifier == "embedTopSearchesVC" {

            if self.childViewControllers.count > 0 {
                self.swapFromViewController(self.childViewControllers[0] , toViewController: self.secondViewController!)
            } else {
                self.addChildViewController(segue.destinationViewController)

                let destView: UIView = (segue.destinationViewController).view
                destView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
                self.view.addSubview(destView)

                segue.destinationViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

            }

        } else if segue.identifier == "embedBecomeAHelper"{
            if self.childViewControllers.count > 0 {
                self.swapFromViewController(self.childViewControllers[0], toViewController: self.thirdViewController!)
            } else {
                self.addChildViewController(segue.destinationViewController)

                let destView: UIView = (segue.destinationViewController).view
                destView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
                self.view.addSubview(destView)

                segue.destinationViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

            }
        }
    }

    func swapFromViewController(fromViewController: UIViewController, toViewController: UIViewController) -> Void {
        toViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
        fromViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)

        self.addChildViewController(toViewController)

        self.transitionFromViewController(fromViewController, toViewController: toViewController, duration: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil, completion: { finished in  fromViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
            toViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
            self.transitionInProgress = false
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Showing code would be helpful to resolve the issue

Comment: I agree, I just wasn't sure what to show as I thought it would be a lot. I'll edit my answer and add it in.

Comment: @ZaidPathan thanks for the code edit :)

Comment: I think I'm not able to get issue from this code, may be we can go through screen sharing. contact me if needed.